# AWS EC2 Disable disableApiTermination from the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS, I created an EC2 instance and I want to terminate it.

However, when I created it, I set disableApiTermination to True, and now, when I'm trying to terminate it, I receive this message:

```
The instance 'i-03bd46dff8fca8db7' may not be terminated. 
Modify its 'disableApiTermination' instance attribute and try again.
```

I would like to set disableApiTermination to false, but I can't find this option on the console, do you know how I turn this off ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called Termination Protection. To disable it:

1. Select the instance, and choose Actions, Instance Settings, Change Termination Protection.
2. Choose Yes, Disable.

Comment: It worked, thank you ! 

Comment: You are very welcome!